# How to use CompareValidator to check that the text does not contain any number

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, comparevalidator

I try to validate the name and surname. I need to check if the user's input is without numeric character but when I run the code, no error message appear. Here's my code:

```
            <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator2" runat="server" 
                ControlToValidate="TextBox3" ErrorMessage="ชื่อต้องเป็นตัวอักษรเท่านั้น" 
                ForeColor="Red" Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="String" ValidationGroup="Group1">*</asp:CompareValidator>
            <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator3" runat="server" 
                ControlToValidate="TextBox6" ErrorMessage="นามสกุลต้องเป็นตัวอักษรเท่านั้น" 
                ForeColor="Red" Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="String" ValidationGroup="Group1">*</asp:CompareValidator>
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use **RegexExpressionValidator** in addition to CompareValidator

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="ValidName" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Name" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Group1" ValidationExpression="^[^0-9]+$">syntax error...</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: It's validate correctly but it's only pass if it's all English language. I can't type Thai language.

Comment: I think you didn't understand me :D i meant i edited my code !

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `CustomValidator` instead , as follows :

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="NoneNumeric" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtNoneNumeric" ClientValidationFunction="IsNoneNumeric">Enter Only None Numeric Values !</asp:CustomValidator>
```

and write a javascript function as follows :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function IsNoneNumeric(sender, arguments) {
        var NoneNumeric = true;
        for (count = arguments.Value.length; count > 0; count--) {
            TempChar = arguments.Value.substring(count, count + 1);
            if (numString.indexOf(TempChar, 0) != -1) {
                NoneNumeric = false;
            }
            if (NoneNumeric == true) {
                arguments.IsValid = true;
            }
            else {
                arguments.IsValid = false;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Where should I put this script.

Comment: inside the html  <head> tag